# For in random order no repeating numbers

Tags: php, random, for-loop

Whats the best way to do a random "for" without repeating any number?

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

I think some ways but are so complicated with a lot amount of code..
There is a standard function to do what im willing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$numbers = range(1,10);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach($numbers as $i) {
    // do stuff
}
```

That will give you the numbers 1 to 10 with no repetition in a random order.

Answer (score 1):

```
$range = range(1,10);
shuffle($range);
foreach ($range as $i) {
    echo $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with a range of numbers and then shuffle:

```
$array = range(1, 10);
shuffle($array);
for ($i=0,$c=count($array); $i<$c; $i++) {
    echo $array[$i] . "\n";
}
```