# php include random file with no repeat on pageload

Tags: php, random, include, glob

I am currently using mt_rand to display a random file from the specified folder each time the page is loaded.

After doing lots of searching i think i need to create an array and then shuffle the array, but not sure how to go about this.

Most of the examples i have found use an array and then echo the results where as i'm trying to include the result.

```
<?php
$fict = glob("spelling/*.php");
$fictional = $fict[mt_rand(0, count($fict) -1)];
include ($fictional);
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: your code snippet should work perfectly? I don't understand your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [For in random order no repeating numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886704/for-in-random-order-no-repeating-numbers)

Comment: Sorry i only wrote this in the title, php include random file with no repeat on pageload. currently it repeats the same file sometimes.

Comment: then you should store your $fictional in the _SESSION and use it when present, if not use the code you have in the OP

Comment: Thanks herbert but i'm trying to include one not display all randomly

Comment: I believe @Rufinus is on to something with sessions. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17898500/911182)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use session cookies to hold a random, non-repeating list of files. Actually, for security, the session cookie should only store a list of *indices* into an array of files.

For example, suppose we have the following file list in an array:

```
index           file
----------------------------
  0      spelling/file1.txt
  1      spelling/file2.txt
  2      spelling/file3.txt
  3      spelling/file4.txt
```

We can create an array of the indices, *e.g.* `array(0,1,2,3)`, shuffle them to get something like `array(3,2,0,1)`, and store *that* list in the cookie. Then, as we progress through this random list of indices, we get the sequence:

```
spelling/file4.txt
spelling/file3.txt
spelling/file1.txt
spelling/file2.txt
```

The cookie also stores the current position in this list of indices and when it reaches the end, we reshuffle and start over.

I realize all this may sound a bit confusing so maybe this gorgeous diagram will help:
[image: Gorgeous Diagram]

… or maybe some code:

```php
<?php

$fictional = glob("spelling/*.php");    // list of files
$max_index = count($fictional) - 1;
$indices = range( 0, $max_index );      // list of indices into list of files

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['indices']) || !isset($_SESSION['current'])) {

    shuffle($indices);
    $_SESSION['indices'] = serialize($indices);
    $_SESSION['current'] = 0;           // keep track of which index we're on

} else {

    $_SESSION['current']++;             // increment through the list of indices
                                        // on each reload of the page

}

// Get the list of indices from the session cookie
$indices = unserialize($_SESSION['indices']);

// When we reach the end of the list of indices,
// reshuffle and start over.
if ($_SESSION['current'] > $max_index) {

    shuffle($indices);
    $_SESSION['indices'] = serialize($indices);
    $_SESSION['current'] = 0;

}

// Get the current position in the list of indices
$current = $_SESSION['current'];

// Get the index into the list of files
$index = $indices[$current];

// include the pseudo-random, non-repeating file
include( $fictional[$index] );

?>
```

Comment: The errors indicate that `$fictional[$index]` is an empty string and may somehow be related to `glob`. Comment out the include line and add `var_dump( $fictional );`. One of the entries is probably empty. Also bare in mind that the code snippet isn't intended to be copy/paste, but more of a guideline to get you moving in the right direction. It's not necessarily universally applicable.