# Store random array in session cookie and loop through it

Tags: php, session-cookies, shuffle

I have an array `$files` containing a list of php files from a directory. One of these files should be randomly included in a page each time it is loaded. Therefore I shuffled the array `shuffle($files);`.

To avoid that the same php include is loaded in a row, I’d like the shuffled array to be stored in a session cookie, so there’s kind of a loop through the array on each time the page is refreshed. When the end of the array is reached a new shuffled array should be generated, …

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892321/php-include-random-file-with-no-repeat-on-pageload) but it didn’t work for me.
Here’s what I have so far:

PHP

```
// Get files from directory and store them in an array
$files = glob("teaser-images/*.php");

// Start session
session_start();

// Randomize array and store it in a session cookie
shuffle($files);

// If there’s already a cookie find the corresponding index and loop trough the array each refresh
if (isset($_SESSION['last_index'])) {
  $_SESSION['last_index'] = …

  // If the end of the array is reached shuffle it again and start all over
}

// If there’s no cookie start with the first value in the array        
else {
  $_SESSION['last_index'] = …
}

// Include the php file
include($random_file);
```

Comment: You provided a link to another answer and said it doesn't work for you. How does it "not work"? What is the error?

Comment: I found no errors but there’s nothing displayed …

Answer (score 0):

is this what your looking for?

```
<?php

// Initialize the array
$files = array();

session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION['FILES']);
// Check if this is the first time visit or if there are files left to randomly select
if( !isset($_SESSION['FILES']) OR count($_SESSION['FILES']) == 0 ){
    // If its the first time visit or all files have already been selected -> reload with all files
    $files = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    echo("first time visit / reloaded / ");
}
else{
    // Use the files that are left
    $files = $_SESSION['FILES'];
    echo("use the files that are left / ");
}

// Get a random file
$selectedFile = array_rand($files);
var_dump($selectedFile);

//include the random file
print_r($files[$selectedFile]);
// Remove randome file from array
unset($files[$selectedFile]);

// Set the session with the remaining files
$_SESSION['FILES'] = $files;

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I’m afraid, the code doesn’t work properly for me. I think there’s something wrong with the reloading when all files have been selected. http://viper-7.com/DsxTP8

Comment: I used the array_rand wrong ;) but now it should work

Comment: Suppose that the last index *before* reloading is 4. How do you make sure that the first index *after* reloading is not 4?

Comment: Thanks for modifying, YANTHO! And smart question, d0c! — Is it possible to start exactly the same order that is randomly generated when the site is visited for the first time over again after all files have been selected?

Comment: Yes, i think the easiest way is to create an array with the values at random places on the first time visit and use that array to reset the array that is being used.

Comment: YANTHO, do you have a snippet for you suggestion? Many thanks in advance!